# Setting height of div equal to containing div

Tags: html, css

i have the following simple script

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="left">
    <div id="menu">
     <ul>
      <li>menu</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="left_ad">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="middle">
    some text here...
   </div>
   <div id="right">
    <div id="right_ad">
     <div id="ad2">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

### css:

```
#content
{

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;

}
#left
{
 float: left;
 width:25%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:-5000px;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-bottom:5000px;

}
#middle
{
 background-image:url("http://localhost/kino/img/theme.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 float: left;
 width:50%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:-5000px;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-bottom:5000px;
}
#right
{
 float: left;
 width:25%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:-1px;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:-5000px;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-bottom:5000px;
}
#left_ad
{
 background-image:url("http://localhost/kino/img/lens1.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 min-height:498px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top:31px;
 padding:0;
 width: 188px;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}
```

---

as you see, **left**, **middle** and **right**  have the same size of heigth, which is equal to max of them.
and now, what is the question, i want **left_ad** to have the same heigth too. how can i set the heigth of **left_id** is equal to `left`?
thanks

Comment: Don't use paddings and margins to size your element. This is what's causing your left_ad to not size how you want.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks  are you sure? i think it has nothing to do with my problem. i just need to dinamicaly change the heigth ov left_ad, it must follow to left

Comment: Yes, I put your code into JSbin and played with it a bit, seems that when you size your elements with padding, the child element left_ad has no height to go on and wil lonly size to 100% of what's there, not the padded size. 

As far as I can see, you'll have to actually add height attributes to your CSS: `left {height:100px;` or whatever.

http://jsfiddle.net/76mm8/ jsbin link

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks  but when i insert such data, that right div's height become more then 100px, my left div also will start to look like this. but it won't have the height in css, so left_ad won't have the height too.

Comment: It might help if we had a live example we could take a look at, seeing as you say it's generated dynamically, we'd be able to help you more if you post a link. Also the right div's height is set so because of the incredible paddong of 5000px. Take a look at that JSbin link I gave you. http://jsfiddle.net/76mm8/1/

Answer (score 2):

left_ad height is set to 100% which means it inherits its height from the parent div. You need to set a height for left div.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
height:600px; /*or whatever you want*/
```

to your `left {` div CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/